# XML schema for Excel XML exportation

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, export, excel-2007

I'm getting mad trying to create an XML schema to transform an Excel file to an XML file.
The sample .xls file has two cell with

- the name of the event and
- the name of the location
  then there's a table with a session for every column and a rider's name for every row.

[This is a screenshot of the spreadsheet.](http://www.cheekychaz.com/example/1.jpg)

To save as XML data I need to make the XML schema and I've achived this using the [Excel 2003 Add-in: XML Tools Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3108).
So I have this XML schema:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>
<!-- Created from XmlMap.Name: Results_mapping -->
<!-- XmlMap.DataBinding.SourceUrl:  -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element nillable="true" name="Results">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="rider" form="unqualified">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" name="Column1" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:integer" name="Column_1st_session" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:integer" name="Column_2nd_session" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:integer" name="Column_3rd_session" form="unqualified"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

which generate the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <rider>
        <Column1>Mike</Column1>
        <Column_1st_session>5</Column_1st_session>
        <Column_2nd_session>10</Column_2nd_session>
        <Column_3rd_session>8</Column_3rd_session>
    </rider>
    <rider>
        <Column1>John</Column1>
        <Column_1st_session>5</Column_1st_session>
        <Column_2nd_session>9</Column_2nd_session>
        <Column_3rd_session>8</Column_3rd_session>
    </rider>
    <rider>
        <Column1>Lea</Column1>
        <Column_1st_session>4</Column_1st_session>
        <Column_2nd_session>9</Column_2nd_session>
        <Column_3rd_session>8</Column_3rd_session>
    </rider>
</Results>
```

That's not completely bad but I'd like to have something like

```
<rider name="Mike">
<session name="1st_session">5</session>
<session name="2nd_session">10</session>
<session name="3rd_session">8</session>
</rider>
```

can anybody please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tutorials and manuals I've found a really useful guide about how to make the mapping of the *xls file automatically and without plug-in...very good! http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/using-xml-in-excel.php