# Import excel sheet with many tables and formulas to mysql in PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to import many excel sheets into Mysql. The file contains many sheets and the data is arranged in different manner with many tables and formulas.
Is it possible to import the excel sheet ,so that the entire data and formula is preserved and the user can store and view the entire excel in the webpage.

Here is a sample of the data
[image]
I searched a lot for it..But couldnt find a solution for this complicated situation..

Is it possible with any library like PHPExcel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think what you're looking for is https://www.google.ca/sheets/about/

Comment: @Augwa No..im supposed to do the coding of an app which can convert excel sheets to the web

Comment: Consider the effort required to build google sheets, and that's what you're in for.

Comment: @Augwa Exactly..but they want an app for their own...May be thats not possible.. :( Anyway thanks

Comment: It's possible; but not at a cost and timescale that they'd be willing to accept accept, even with the assistance of libraries like PHPExcel

Answer (score 0):

You should "massage" that data a little bit. Copy the data into a few more spreadsheets and output to CSV. That data will then be in a more universal format that can be parsed using one of the several CSV parsers for PHP. If you don't you are going to have a lot of problems with character encodings otherwise. The other reason is that you are going to spend way more time writing conditional logic if you don't. You would need to break this out into, what I see in your screenshot, is several different data types.

Comment: Yes..you are right.. But now im in need of a situation where users will upload any sort of sheet which must be stored in web..I guess they want to make an app to preserve all their excel sheets

Comment: You should just store the file as-is on the web server and keep reference to it in the db. If you need the contents to be searchable, you should checkout Amazon Elastic Search. Someone has already written an [import for Excel](https://github.com/codingchili/parser-excel-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to generate a sheet with only the data you want to upload, this could be done manually or with some VBA code.
Then you should save this data in a format easier to manage than xls: for example CSV or XML. Also this point could be done with some VBA lines.

- If you decided to save the data in XML follow [this](http://subinsb.com/insert-xml-file-contents-to-mysql-database-table-using-php) tutorial on how to import data and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374958/xml-schema-for-excel-xml-exportation) about how to map the file before export in XML.
- If you decided to save the data in CSV follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066961/import-data-from-excel-in-php) answer.

I think that you could also take a look at [this](http://www.discussdesk.com/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-PHP.htm).